# Where to put model code in ORM ? (Eloquent)

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, eloquent

I dont quite understand where my code goes for this orm.

```
class Brand_model extends MY_Model {

public function add_brand($name, $size)
{
//goal:
//        $sql = "insert into brand (name, size_id) values (?,?)";
//        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($name, $size));

    $brand = new self();
    $brand->name=$name;
    $brand->size=$size;
    $brand->save();


}
```

This produces a new row in the database, in the appropriate table, but with no data inside of it. However I am sure those variables are filled. Any ideas?

My design pattern pre orm is to put almost everything in the model. That way if multiple controllers need the same data structure, i call a function once and it handles all the validation/etc.

THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please find the link for eloquent and codeigniter integration

http://mannyisles.com/using-eloquent-orm-inside-codeigniter.html

Answer (score 0):

To use the ORM, first of all, you would need the connection set up. You can look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592116/laravel-eloquent-integration-in-codeigniter/30614649#30614649). It tells you how to set up eloquent DB connection.

Once it is done, you need to create a model, which would extends the ORM, and do all your DB calls using that model.

You can create a file - let's say, FooModel.php like this:

```
<?php

namespace Models\FooModel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FooModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sample_table';
    protected $fillable = array('comma', 'seperated', 'column', 'names');

    protected $hidden = array('id');
    public $timestamps = true;
}
?>
```

`$fillable` tells eloquent which columns you want to write into. you can ignore the auto incremented columns and the columns with default values.
`$timestamps` handle your created_at and updated_at columns, if you have any.

When you have to create the row, you can call the eloquent [create()](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete) function. This function requires an associative array with column names as key and values as the corresponding value you wanna insert to that column.

```
$row = array('name' => 'Foo',
     'email' => 'foo@bar.com'
);
```

You can then just call the create function, with `$row` as a parameter.

`$response = FooModel::create($row);`

If you do a `var_dump($response);` you can see the status of the `create()`. `true` for success or the error message.

For further info you can check out the [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent). It's really not that hard!

Cheers! :)