# Laravel Eloquent integration in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, eloquent

I am trying to use eloquent orm inside codeigniter.

Following is my composer.json file

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "illuminate/database": "5.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "application/models"
                    ]
    }
```

In index.php file I have I added

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

I have create `Eloquent.php` file in application/models to initiate eloquent

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$CI = & get_instance();

$config = $CI->db;

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$config->hostname.';dbname='.$config->database, $config->username, $config->password);

$drivers = array(
'mysql' => '\Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection',
'pgsql' => '\Illuminate\Database\PostgresConnection',
'sqlite' => '\Illuminate\Database\SQLiteConnection',
);

$conn = new $drivers['mysql']($pdo, $config->database, $config->dbprefix);      

$resolver = new Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolver;
$resolver->addConnection('default', $conn);
$resolver->setDefaultConnection('default');

\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setConnectionResolver($resolver);
```

following is my `Foo.php` model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once(APPPATH.'models/Eloquent.php');

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Foo extends Eloquent
{
    public $table = "foos";
}
```

In `Foos.php` controller I have tried something like following

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Foos extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        var_dump(Foo::all());
    }
}
```

But it is returning following error.

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Foos::$db

Filename: models/Eloquent.php

Line Number: 5
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered loading it as a third-party library instead? It just seems easier to me...

Comment: Third party is obviously another good option. but I just want to solve it first.

Comment: Add `require ‘vendor/autoload.php';` just before the codeigniter bootsrap

Comment: it is already added, just forgot to mention it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are missing is another class Capsule. Check your vendor folder. It is located in `/.../vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Capsule/Manager.php`

You can use this as

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
$CONFIG['db'] = array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'testDB',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => ''
    );
$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection($CONFIG['db']);
// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Once you have made this as global, you can call it using:
FooModel.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
class Foo extends Eloquent
{
    public $table = "foos";
}
```

and call it as:

```
use \path\to\Foo;
Foo::all();
```

You were missing the bootEloquent() function call.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I have this working well in my CI 3.0 app, but I am curious how I would access the laravel "DB" class using the method above. How would i go about using the following code "DB::statement('drop table users');"

Comment: @albertleao, you cannot use "DB" class. You can use "Capsule::" class however.  Check this out: https://github.com/illuminate/database